# How to display a lot of points on the map Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to show more than 1,000 points on the map.
Application begins to slow and falls because overloaded memory.
My code (I get the coordinates of points from the server):

```
for outputValueArray in dataOfOutputValueArray {
   var latitudeAddOutputValue : Double? = outputValueArray["latitude_add"].double
   var longitudeAddOutputValue : Double? = outputValueArray["longitude_add"].double

   if (latitudeAddOutputValue != nil && longitudeAddOutputValue != nil) {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
           self.circuitPoint(latitudeAddOutputValue!, 
                longitudeAdd: longitudeAddOutputValue!).map = self.viewMap!})       
         }
   }
```

circuitPoint:

```
func circuitPoint(latitudeAdd: Double, longitudeAdd: Double) -> GMSCircle{
        var circleCenter =
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudeAdd, longitudeAdd);
        var circ = GMSCircle(position: circleCenter, radius: 1)
        circ.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.50)
        circ.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.50)
        circ.strokeWidth = 5
        return circ
    }
```

Ideally I would like to use Tile Layers ([this documentation is very poor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/tiles)) in Google Maps SDK for iOS but I do not know how to:

1. Show point in the right place on the tile.
2. How to create an image of
   the desired size on the server (or in app) for Tile Layers

On the final to be like this
[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: You might want to see this QA: [Calculate lat lon bounds for individual tile generated from gdal2tiles](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/17278)

Comment: [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/tiles#high_dpi_tiles_for_retina_devices) says that you can set the "titleSize" property of a TileLayer, for retina device, you can set it to 512, and 256 for non-retina one.